# in the oracle how to define a foreign key in the nested table?

Tags: sql, oracle, object, relational-database

i need to add a foreign key refeences to the nested table how can i do that?

here is my oracle code here i my issue line is starting with "##" tag while executing this it says an error "missing keyword"

what wrong with the following code?

```
CREATE TYPE Doctor_type AS OBJECT(

    regNo char(100),
    name varchar2(50),
    specialization varchar2(50)
)
/

CREATE TYPE HospitalVisits_type AS OBJECT(
    visitNo char(10),
    hosCharge char(10),
    makedate date,
    Doctor REF Doctor_type
)
not final
/

CREATE TYPE Make_type AS TABLE OF HospitalVisits_type;
/

CREATE TYPE Patient_type AS OBJECT(
    id char(10),
    name varchar2(50),
    dateofBirth date,
    phone varchar2(10),
    dependents Make_type
)
/


CREATE  TYPE Admission_type UNDER HospitalVisits_type (

    dischDate date
)
/

CREATE  TYPE OPDVisit_type UNDER HospitalVisits_type(

    docCharge char(10)
)
/

CREATE TABLE Doctor OF Doctor_type(regNo primary key )
/

CREATE TABLE Patient OF Patient_type(id primary key)NESTED TABLE dependents STORE AS HospitalVisits_Table
/

##ALTER TABLE HospitalVisits_Table ADD CONSTRAINT Doc_FK FOREIGN KEY(Doctor) REFERENCES Doctor(regNo) 
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Nested tables aren't "tables", really. They're just collections, or arrays.